# inability to add an item in empty array using sate reducer function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state , reducer modules ,
the point of doing this is to created 2 states the are relative one to another , in first action  (add box) I add to the first state box an element and also created an empty array in the other state children, that will get filled with element once the second function will be called (on demand). the problem is I am not able to push items when the second function is called in to the empty array that is the result of the first function being called, could you help me with syntax ?

```js
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BOX:
      return {
        ...state,
        boxes: [...state.boxes, { id: action.id, index: action.index }],
        childern: [...state.childern, []],
      };

    case ADD_CHILD:
      return {
        // push data in to already existing array !!
        ...state,
        ...state.childern[action.index[{ id: action.payload }]],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```js
// State Module
const AppState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    boxes: [],
    childern: [],
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);
  console.log(state);
  const AddBox = (id, i) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_BOX,
      id: id,
      index: i,
    });
  };

  const AddBoxChild = (id, i) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_CHILD,
      payload: id,
      index: i,
    });
  };

  return (
    <appContext.Provider
      value={{
        boxes: state.boxes,
        childern: state.childern,
        AddBox,
        AddBoxChild,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </appContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppState;
```

Comment: what is `state.childern[action.index[{ id: action.payload}]]` (in the ADD_CHILD case of the reducer) supposed to do? This does not even look like valid JS syntax to me. (In fact, I think it won't be a syntax error but will stringify the object as "object Object" to treat as a key in `action.index`)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would add something to the children array

```
case ADD_CHILD:
      return {
        // push data in to already existing array !!
        ...state,
        childern: [...state.childern, action.index[{ id: action.payload }]],
      };
```

Also don't do this in ADD_BOX

```
childern: [...state.childern, []], // [[]] <- this is the result
```

You are adding an array to the array (nesting arrays)

Comment: thanks , actually I want to nest the array so every father element will map the items from that specific nested array witch will have items inside of it, any better idea for a seperate state, solution?